# 'System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<T>' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors, asp.net-web-api

```
var cnt = new ObjectContent<int>(1, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

The line above gives an compiler error below

*'System.Net.Http.ObjectContent' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments*

How to fix this problem?

UPD: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944687(v=vs.108).aspx have 2, 3 and 3 arguments

Comment: this code -> var cnt = new ObjectContent(typeof(int), 1, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()); throws 'System.Net.Http.ObjectContent' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments

Comment: The error is quite clear.  The constructor for ObjectContent does not take 2 or 3 arguments, yet you are passing 2 or 3 arguments.  What is the signature for the ObjectContent constructor?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.objectcontent.objectcontent(v=vs.108).aspx have 3, 4 and 4 arguments

Comment: It looks like you're using the generic version, if so, then your code should be correct, because it has a constructor with 2 arguments:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944551(v=vs.108).aspx  That's very peculiar.

Comment: Likely solution to my problem below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What release of Web API are you using? It could be because the constructor is internal if you are using the Beta release

Basically in one of the pre-releases the ObjectContent constructor was made internal meaning you will have to use the following code:

```
HttpRequestMessage<T> request = new HttpRequestMessage<T>();  
ObjectContent<T> content = request.CreateContent<T>(operationInput, 
new MediaTypeHeaderValue(Constants.ContentTypeXml), 
new MediaTypeFormatterCollection() { new XmlMediaTypeFormatter() }, new FormatterSelector());
```

see the following link

http://blog.sacaluta.com/2012/02/aspnet-web-api-objectcontent.html

Comment: When answering a question by providing links to external sources, always include the important points from that source in your answer, as links might die over time.

Comment: Apologies this was my first answer here. I am just reviewing the best practices now. I will edit the answer shortly

Comment: The link is dead.